# Names of convex geometry journals

Tags: convex-geometry, journals, research

What are the names of the research journals that focus on convex geometry?  I know of "Advances in Geometry" and "Discrete & Computational Geometry" but no others.

Context of question:  I am a graduate student who recently submitted a paper to a geometry research journal.  They did not accept my paper and suggested that I send my paper to a journal that focuses on convex geometry in particular.

Comment: Not the best question for this forum, but not too bad.  You could do a web search and likely get a better answer than asking here, but I would put it on the editor and ask them what journals they think of that do such specialization.  Gerhard "Treat Such Responses With Respect" Paseman, 2017.07.17.

Comment: Ah, so we're tallking about (convex geometry) journals, not convex (geometry journals).

Comment: I would search mathscinet for articles within the last 10 years in MSC 52, and see where they are published.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of such a journal (and as someone who has been the editor in charge of convex geometry in a couple of good journals, I would probably know). My suggestion is to do one of the following:

Meditate on your paper, and try to discover more connections to other fields.

Go down the list of journals and see if one of them has an editor who might like the paper.

Either post the preprint link, or just email me (or your favorite convex geometer) for advice.

I would order the suggestions as $1>3>2.$

Comment: Upon re-reading the editor's email, I see that he actually says a journal with a "strong focus on 'Convex Geometry.'"  Do such journals, in your experience, exist?

Comment: @math4 It depends on how you interpret "focus".

Answer (score 2):

[Geombinatorics](http://geombina.uccs.edu/) is a journal on open problems of combinatorial and
discrete geometry and related areas. The journal is edited by Prof. [Alexander "Sasha" Soifer](http://www.uccs.edu/~asoifer/): he used to have a MO account, but I can't find him in the list of [users](https://mathoverflow.net/users) of the site anymore.